# Tweepy AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get tweets using `tweepy` but I am running into this error:

> AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search'

Code:

```
import tweepy

# Authentication
consumerKey = "Type your consumer key here"
consumerSecret = "Type your consumer secret here"
accessToken = "Type your accedd token here"
accessTokenSecret = "Type your access token secret here"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
#Sentiment Analysis

def percentage(part,whole):
    return 100 * float(part)/float(whole) 

keyword = input("Please enter keyword or hashtag to search: ")
noOfTweet = int(input ("Please enter how many tweets to analyze: "))


tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=keyword).items(noOfTweet)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't undestand what is your problem. You should describe it in question's body, not in title. and you should add code and FULL error message - and in editor you should use special function to format code.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1):

use `api.search_tweets` instead of `api.search`
tweepy v.4.0.0 has changed it..

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search(q=keyword)).items(noOfTweet)
```